# Output data of JSON Array as HTML

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to create an overlay for my twitch stream, which display not only the recent follower but a certain amount of them in chronological order.

Here a visual representation:

[image: latest follower bottom]

(Styling is done with HTML/CSS)

I've already managed to get the JSON but I don't know how to echo the names for each `['follows']['user']['display_name']`

This is the API:
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/kazutode/follows?limit=5&offset=0&client_id=nht9j8w0u4xazpm1fdc2fmkrqvoici

Here's my code so far (It's not alot, basically nothing xD)

```
<?php

$clientID = "nht9j8w0u4xazpm1fdc2fmkrqvoici";
$channel = "kazutode";
$limit = 5;
$offset = 0;

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'.$channel.'/follows?limit='.$limit.'&offset='.$offset.'&client_id='.$clientID), true);

?>
```

I know, I know. I should use curl but I don't know how so I stick to json_decode.

Can someone teach me how to get the wanted data out of the `['follows']` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a foreach loop. Here is some PHP+HTML mixed to give you an idea:

```
$table = '';
$table .= '<table>';
foreach($response['follows'] as $entry) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td>'.$entry['created_at'].'</td>';
    $table .= '<td>'.$entry['user']['display_name'].'</td>';
    $table .= '<td><a class="your-custom-class" href="'.$entry['_links']['self'].'">View channel</a></td>';
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
```

Comment: Haven't thought it would be so easy. I will try it immediately :) Thanks in advance.